# Erro ao importar imagem: Allowed memory size

Tags: php, imagem, processamento-de-imagens

Estou usando um script simples para recortar a imagem, ao recortar algumas imagens ele dá esse erro:

> Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   155648 bytes)  in /home/site/public_html/admin/controller/foto.php on
>   line 65

O estranho é que a imagem tem só 65kb, alguém sabe o que pode ser? Tem como eu gerar um log mais detalhado?

abaixo o script e a linha 65 comentada:

```
//RECORTAR E IMPORTAR AS FOTOS NO FTP ****************************************
foreach($_FILES as $key => $ft){
    if($ft['tmp_name']!=''){
        $pastafoto = $root.'imagens/usuarios/';
        $photo_url = $ft['tmp_name'];
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($photo_url);
        $nomearquivo=$ft['name'];
        if($key=='foto'){
            $proporcao=1;
            $tamanho='150';
        }elseif($key=='capa'){
            $tamanho='1060';
            $proporcao=6.057142857142857;
        }

        if(!is_dir($pastafoto.$usuario['id'])){
            mkdir($pastafoto.$usuario['id'], 0755);
        }
        $dest = $pastafoto.$usuario['id'].'/' . $nomearquivo;
        $source_image = $photo_url;
        $nome=$nomearquivo;
        $destination = $pastafoto.$usuario['id'].'/'.$local.'/'.$nome;
        $tn_w = $tamanho;
        $tn_h = ($tamanho * $proporcao);
        $quality = 80;
        $wmsource = '';
        $success = image_handler($source_image,$destination,$tn_w,$tn_h,$quality,$wmsource);
        $sql = "UPDATE ptp_usuarios SET {$key}='{$nome}' WHERE id = {$usuario['id']}";
        $result = $db->prepare( $sql );
        $result->execute();
    }
}
//FUNÇÃO COPIA FOTO
function image_handler($source_image,$destination,$tn_w = 100,$tn_h = 100,$quality = 100,$wmsource = false) {
    $info = getimagesize($source_image);
    $imgtype = image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]);
    switch ($imgtype) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image);
        break;
        case 'image/gif':
        $source = imagecreatefromgif($source_image);
        break;
        case 'image/png':
        $source = imagecreatefrompng($source_image);
        break;
        default:
        die('Invalid image type.');
    }
    $src_w = imagesx($source);
    $src_h = imagesy($source);
    $src_ratio = $src_w/$src_h;
    if ($tn_w/$tn_h > $src_ratio) {
        $new_h = $tn_w/$src_ratio;
        $new_w = $tn_w;
    } else {
        $new_w = $tn_h*$src_ratio;
        $new_h = $tn_h;
    }
    $x_mid = $new_w/2;
    $y_mid = $new_h/2;

    // Now actually apply the crop and resize!

//ESSA LINHA ABAIXO É A QUE FALA QUE DEU ERRO! ***********************************************

    $newpic = imagecreatetruecolor(round($new_w), round($new_h));
    imagecopyresampled($newpic, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $src_w, $src_h);
    $final = imagecreatetruecolor($tn_w, $tn_h);
    imagecopyresampled($final, $newpic, 0, 0, ($x_mid-($tn_w/2)), ($y_mid-($tn_h/2)), $tn_w, $tn_h, $tn_w, $tn_h);
                    // If a watermark source file is specified, get the information about the watermark as well. This is the same thing we did above for the source image.
    if($wmsource) {
        $info = getimagesize($wmsource);
        $imgtype = image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]);
        switch ($imgtype) {
            case 'image/jpeg':
            $watermark = imagecreatefromjpeg($wmsource);
            break;
            case 'image/gif':
            $watermark = imagecreatefromgif($wmsource);
            break;
            case 'image/png':
            $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($wmsource);
            break;
            default:
            die('Invalid watermark type.');
        }
        // Determine the size of the watermark, because we're going to specify the placement from the top left corner of the watermark image, so the width and height of the watermark matter.
        $wm_w = imagesx($watermark);
        $wm_h = imagesy($watermark);
                        // Now, figure out the values to place the watermark in the bottom right hand corner. You could set one or both of the variables to "0" to watermark the opposite corners, or do your own math to put it somewhere else.
                        //$wm_x = $tn_w - $wm_w;
                        //$wm_y = $tn_h - $wm_h;
        $wm_x = ($tn_w / 2) - ($wm_w / 2);
        $wm_y = ($tn_h / 2) - ($wm_h / 2);
                        // Copy the watermark onto the original image
                        // The last 4 arguments just mean to copy the entire watermark
        imagecopy($final, $watermark, $wm_x, $wm_y, 0, 0, $tn_w, $tn_h);
    }
                    // Ok, save the output as a jpeg, to the specified destination path at the desired quality.
                    // You could use imagepng or imagegif here if you wanted to output those file types instead.
    if(Imagejpeg($final,$destination,$quality)) {
    return true;
    }
                    // If something went wrong
    return false;
}
```

Comment: a resposta te ajudou? Se sim, procure marcá-la para ajudar outros colegas.

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia, você pode verificar o seu php.ini a diretiva `memory_limit` altere para algo em torno de **1024M** ou mais.

Alguns retornos referente a limite de memória:

```
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 8388608 Bytes Exhausted - 8 MB
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 16777216 Bytes Exhausted - 16 MB
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 33554432 Bytes Exhausted - 32 MB
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 67108864 Bytes Exhausted - 64 MB
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted - 128 MB
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 268435456 Bytes Exhausted - 256 MB
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 536870912 Bytes Exhausted - 512 MB
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 1073741824 Bytes Exhausted - 1 GB
```

Como pode ver a sua está em 256MB.

Você também pode verificar essas outras diretivas que também são referente a upload de arquivos (mas a primeira solução acima já resolve seu problema):

```
upload_max_filesize
file_uploads
upload_max_filesize
max_file_uploads
post_max_size
max_input_time
```

Lembrando que após realizar esta alteração no seu php.ini seu apache deve ser reiniciado para que funcione.

Caso queira colocar a solução em seu arquivo use o código abaixo. Mas indico alterar o php.ini.

```
<?php
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); // no caso usando 1G
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: eu fiz, mas agora apareceu: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 884998144) (tried to allocate 155648 bytes) in /home/site/public_html/admin/controller/foto.php on line 65

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo qual é qtd de memória RAM do seu servidor?

Comment: ixe, não sei te dizer, não consigo ver isso no php.ini ne? uso o cpanel, em algum lugar consigo ver?

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo faz o seguinte, entra em contato com sua hospedagem para vc verificar qual é a sua memória RAM, as vezes pode ser servidor compartilhado e está te dando este problema. Outra coisa. altera a diretiva memory_limit para 128MB. Porque eu estou achando que seu servidor não tem muita memória disponível. Usando 128MB pode resolver para vc.

Comment: mas uma dúvida, nessa mensagem ele não ta falando que tem mais espaço do que precisa? allocated 884998144  - tried to allocate 155648 bytes, em teoria ele não deveria funcionar?